# Schedule discord command

Tags: python, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command which allows the user to schedule a task to a specific time.

For example, when the command is used, the bot will wait until 2 PM then it will send a message (of course I don't want to make a `time.sleep` because the users won't be able to use the bot)

Do you know how could I code this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the python package ['schedule'](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#schedule) for that.

It allows you to do things such as:

```
schedule.every().day.at("02:00").do(job)
```

Note that if you'd like to run your task only once, have a look at this section of the documentation: 
https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-run-a-job-only-once